# Format of MAC address sent over network

Tags: c, network-programming, mac-address, libpcap

Given a standard Mac address "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" what format does it need to be in to be sent using libpcap's packet inject?

I load it into the ethernet frame where srcMac is just a char:

```
memcpy(&ethernet.ether_src, srcMac, sizeof(ethernet.ether_src));
```

But in wireshark the address is incorrect. The visible Mac address in wireshark changes depending on what the string is so it's not being overwritten by the default address or anything.

Comment: Naive and uninformed answer, but aren't mac addressed not actually strings? I thought they were just shown that way (actually just a bit string but displayed as a hexadecimal). You could probably use an array of chars,

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about libpcap's requirements, but MAC addresses are expressed on the wire in Ethernet frames as six consecutive octets (bytes).  The 17-character, colon-delimited form (or sometimes space- or hyphen-delimited) is just a convention for human readability.

Comment: "*where srcMac is just a char*" please be more specif here on how `srcMac` is defined and initialised.

Comment: libpcap most likely uses a array of six unsigned characters to hold a MAC address.

Comment: Please also note that the byte order to be used is network byte order (Big Endian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, that in your code `ethernet.ether_src` has type `struct ether_addr` so it is not just a `char*`-string.

So you need to convert ASCII string to Ethernet address, e.g. with function declared as

```
extern struct ether_addr *ether_aton (__const char *__asc) __THROW;
```